# How to get a distinct withSum of related Eloquent models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

My relationships look like this:

- Role - many-to-many - Course
- User - many-to-many - Role

So a user can have many Courses through their Roles. Some courses will be duplicates in that collection, though, because Courses will exist for multiple Roles.

So I have to use `$user->courses()->distinct()->get()` to get a unique list of the actual courses the user has to participate in.

The question is, how do I get distinct related models when using aggregates?

```php
User::withSum('courses as hours_of_training', 'duration');
```

This will give me the sum of the duration of all related courses (including dupes). How do I get rid of the dupes in the aggregate? A solution on how to do this for withCount [exists here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69071613/1501491).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by calling the `withAggregate` function directly and passing the relation as in array in the style `['related_table as alias' => callback]` where the callback does the actual aggregation using the query builder.

The second argument of withAggregate needs to be passed, but can be `null` in this case. It will only be used to build the alias name if none is given.

E.g.

```php
User::withAggregate(['courses as hours_of_training' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(DISTINCT(courses.id))'));
}], null);
```