# How can i count product id row in order details table by using order id in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I can placed here demo table one is **order** table another is **order_details** table

1. in **order** table

| id | order_total | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 300 | Delivered |
| 2 | 500 | Delivered |

2. and another table **order_details**

| id | order_id | product_id | product_price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 150 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 150 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 200 | 1 |

i want this type data

| sl | order_id | count_unique_product_id_row |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |

Comment: What have you tried? Where, specifically are you stuck? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77211506/edit) and include your attempts. If you haven't made any attempts, that's where you need to start. You're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue before asking for help on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use DISTINCT in Laravel's withCount() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914631/use-distinct-in-laravels-withcount-method)

Comment: @AmooAti no not like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve this issue do this code:

```
// get all rows in Order table

$orders = Order::all();

// Loop Through all orders rows

foreach($orders as $order) {

 $orderProductCount = OrderDetails::where("order_id", $order->id)->count();

 echo "Order ID" . $order->id . " Product Count". $orderProductCount;

}
```